# Scrapy scraper not scraping past 1st page

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am following a scrapy tutorial [here](http://python.gotrained.com/scrapy-tutorial-web-scraping-craigslist/#Scrapy_Tutorial_Getting_Started). I have, I believe, got the same code as the tutorial, and yet my scraper only scrapes the first page, then gives the following message regarding my first `Request` to another page, and finishes. Have I perhaps got my second `yield` statement in the wrong place?

> DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'newyork.craigslist.org': https://newyork.craigslist.org/search/egr?s=120>
>
> 2017-05-20 18:21:31 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)

**Here is my code:**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request


class JobsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "jobs"
    allowed_domains = ["https://newyork.craigslist.org/search/egr"]
    start_urls = ['https://newyork.craigslist.org/search/egr/']

    def parse(self, response):
        jobs = response.xpath('//p[@class="result-info"]')

        for job in jobs:
            title = job.xpath('a/text()').extract_first()
            address = job.xpath('span[@class="result-meta"]/span[@class="result-hood"]/text()').extract_first("")[2:-1]
            relative_url = job.xpath('a/@href').extract_first("")
            absolute_url = response.urljoin(relative_url)

            yield {'URL': absolute_url, 'Title': title, 'Address': address}

        # scrape all pages
        next_page_relative_url = response.xpath('//a[@class="button next"]/@href').extract_first()
        next_page_absolute_url = response.urljoin(next_page_relative_url)

        yield Request(next_page_absolute_url, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I figured it out. I had to change this line:

```
allowed_domains = ["https://newyork.craigslist.org/search/egr"]
```

to this:

```
allowed_domains = ["newyork.craigslist.org"]
```

and now it works.